# rss reader Android 4.x.x

Tags: android, rss-reader

I`m beginer in Android, and I try to write a rss reader for Android platform. I used this http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/

tutorial, but it doesn`t work on android 4.2.1 Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Hi, I am the author of that tutorial. Probably a bit later, but here's an updated version with several fixes and improvements: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android-v2/
As ODAXY pointed out "doesn't work" is very little information to say why it does not work. However, the original example had an issue when attempting to run it on a device with Android 3.0 and higher, throwing a NetworkOnMaiThreadException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"tutorial, but it doesn`t work on android 4.2.1"
It's hard to say what is wrong, not enough information.

One of these tutorials should help you with your RSS reader:

[Making a slick RSS Reader in Android](http://www.ingeniumblog.net/2012/01/making-a-slick-rss-reader-in-android/)

[Android RSS Reader Tutorial](http://www.cse.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40814/RSS_Android.pdf)

Comment: I have tested it (your tutorial) on 4.2 emulator and on 2.3.5 real device, 2.3.5 is OK, but 4.2 did not work. You probably have this exception:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception"